# How long it would take to form a conceptual framework to justify a belief?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-therapy, conceptual-framework

From what I understand, the reason to set 1 week as the time between two therapy sessions is for the clients to do homework, which can be: take notes on recursive thoughts and emotions, remember important information that lead to the belief, rewire the brain to build a new habit. (In case of threaten of suicide, it is allowed to have more than one session in one week.)

But from my experience, it takes up to 3 days or less to fully remember the necessary information and organize it in a clear, succinct manner. At then, the person basically satisfies with the answer, and only need to wait for feedback. We can say that the rest 4 days are for them to continue challenging their own view, but it seems that any new information that come up are just minor points, and don't really change the original outline of the answer.

**Question**: How long does it take to assimilate information, recall memory, verbalize [tacit knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge) and organize them as a [conceptual framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_framework) to justify the [belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief)? Is the number 3 a typical number for most people, or is it just me?

I would exclude other non-cognitive factors, like having a day-job. The belief doesn't need to be true either.

A consequence is that the 1 week waiting between sessions could be different in [cognitive therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_therapy), since I think in a logical discussion, any emotions that are evoked will quickly be overcome, as long as the client concentrate on the logic.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19236/7001

Comment: @ChrisRogers it's not a duplicate, since the time to assimilate the information is included in the first 3 days. If the session is totally a logical discussion, not an emotional one (as I think only happens in cognitive therapy), then I would argue that one or two sleeps are enough to assimilate all information.

Comment: @Ooker - the point of your question is [why] is it necessary to wait 1 week between sessions which is why it is a dupe. The fact that you say it takes you 3 days to assimilate information is anecdotal and can be different between people. The 1 week gap is set according to studies linked in the answer in the dupe

Comment: @ChrisRogers I edit the title to focus on the cognitive aspect of it. Is that better?

Comment: Changing the focus to the time it takes to assimilate information etc. does make the question different to the original but, I believe you answered that in the question yourself and it is again, covered in the studies in the answer to the "duplicate question".  These facts could be duplicated in an answer here, but would it really mean that this is a different question?  I will leave that for the community to decide.  Other than that, I would point out that although cognitive therapy sessions may not cover emotional points within an issue, sessions can stir emotions, as you intimated earlier.

Comment: Can you cite where you got the idea that *"more than one session in one week, it's the case of threaten of suicide"*?  Maybe it's the wording in the phrase which is confusing me but it needs citing anyway for site requirements in my mind.

Comment: @ChrisRogers in the other question, it just says that the 1 week time is to allow the clients to assimilate the information and do homework. However, it does not address cognitive therapy specifically.// As for the suicide and emotion bits, I have rewritten them, can you check that? The suicide bit is what I heard from one therapist.